# Get Query in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query from DatabaseReference in Firebase which should return only the parent if it has a value inside a key in my database. Clearly speaking, here is my Firebase database:

```
Posts
     -L2EV2J7FLX5miVn7iRK
          Caption: "first post"
          CurrentUserID: "1Qclku47lEhrB7VWGqSOQuWpPhM2"
          CurrentUserReaction: "notreacted"
          Image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nep..."
          ReactingUser:"0"
          Time: "13:07:00"
          TotalReactions: "3"
```

I have a DatabaseReference which takes in Posts as:

```
databaseRef = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
```

But, I want a query from it, which will return me posts if only the CurrentUserID equals to "1Qclku47lEhrB7VWGqSOQuWpPhM2". I tried doing:

```
Query q = mDatabaseReference.orderByValue().OrderByValue().equalto("1Qclku47lEhrB7VWGqSOQuWpPhM2");
```

Any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Posts")
            .orderByChild("CurrentUserID")
            .equalto("1Qclku47lEhrB7VWGqSOQuWpPhM2");
```